# Swagger, Endpoints and Pathparameters

Tags: web-services, rest, jax-rs, swagger

TLDR: Multiple Pathparameters and Endpoints with Swagger

What i would like to to is some API Endpoint like this:

```
/foo/{id}/bar
```

Now afaik `foo` or the first node in the path is defining the endpoint and also the resource to aqcuire. Therefore a FooApiServiceImpl is generated.

The generated ProjectsApiService stub looks like this atm:

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}/bars") 
...
public Response getBarsByFooId(@ApiParam(value = "The id of the foo with the  bars",required=true ) @PathParam("id") String id)
throws NotFoundException {
    return delegate.getBarByFooId(id);
}
```

Now my wished behaviour would be to GET all the `Bar` resources that are connectted to the `Foo` with the given `{id}`. Kinda like the reverse order. Is this somehow possible?

If this is not possible... then would also like to ask, how can i get url nodes (foo, bar) that are not defined as `{xxx}` paramaters in brackets?

Something like this:

```
public Response getBarsByFooId(String foo, String id, String bar)
throws NotFoundException {
    return delegate.getBarByFooId(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the paths segments, inject a [`UriInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html) in your resource class or method:

```java
@Context
private UriInfo uriInfo;
```

And then invoke [`UriInfo.getPathSegments()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getPathSegments--) from it:

```java
List<PathSegment> segments = uriInfo.getPathSegments();
```

---

See the [`UriInfo.getPathSegments()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getPathSegments--) documentation:

> Get the path of the current request relative to the base URI as a list of [`PathSegment`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/PathSegment.html). **This method is useful when the path needs to be parsed**, particularly when matrix parameters may be present in the path. All sequences of escaped octets in path segments and matrix parameter values are decoded, equivalent to [`getPathSegments(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getPathSegments-boolean-).